# OAuth 2 bad credentials

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I'm getting "bad credentials" when trying to login, no matter the username and password.

I tried creating a bean for the password, changing the authorizeHttpRequest, and adding an authenticationManager but nothing work

```
package Config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager user() {
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                User.withUsername("name")
                    .password("{noop}senha")
                    .authorities("read")
                    .build()
        );
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        return http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .build();   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("name")
            .password("{noop}senha")
            .authorities("read");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Comment: The Override annotation is causing an error saying the methods need to override or implement a supertype method and the methods in configure() are all deprecated